# Is there a Bioperl equivalent of IO::ScalarArray for array of Seq objects?

Tags: perl, arrays, io, bioperl

In Perl, we have [`IO::ScalarArray`](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/IO-stringy-2.110/lib/IO/ScalarArray.pm) for treating the elements of an array like the lines of a file. In BioPerl, we have [`Bio::SeqIO`](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.0/Bio/SeqIO.pm), which can produce a filehandle that reads and writes `Bio::Seq` objects instead of strings representing lines of text. I would like to do a combination of the two: I would like to obtain a handle that reads successive `Bio::Seq` objects from an array of such objects. Is there any way to do this? Would it be trivial for me to implement a module that does this?

My reason for wanting this is that I would like to be able to write a subroutine that accepts either a `Bio::SeqIO` handle or an array of `Bio::Seq` objects, and I'd like to avoid writing separate loops based on what kind of input I get. Perhaps the following would be better than writing my own IO module?

```
sub process_sequences {
    my $input = $_[0];

    # read either from array of Bio::Seq or from Bio::SeqIO
    my $nextseq;
    if (ref $input eq 'ARRAY') {
        my $pos = 0
        $nextseq = sub { return $input->[$pos++] if $pos < @$input}; }
    }
    else {
        $nextseq = sub { $input->getline(); }
    }

    while (my $seq = $nextseq->()) {
        do_cool_stuff_with($seq)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks like it should work. Unless you really want to spend a lot of time solving this problem, go with it until you don't like it anymore. I might have written that like so to avoid typing the variable name several times:

```
my $nextseq = do {
     if (ref $input eq ref [] ) {
         my $pos = 0;  #maybe a state variable if you have Perl 5.10
         sub { return $input->[$pos++] if $pos < @$input} }
         }
     else {
         sub { $input->getline() }
     }
 }
```

If you're interested in iterators, though, check out Mark Jason Dominus's [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/), where he talks about all sorts of ways to do these sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to HOP, which led me to [`Iterator::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~rintaro/Iterator-Simple-0.05/lib/Iterator/Simple.pm)